# google analytics account dynamically

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-analytics

trying to create google analytics account dynamically from ASP.NET MVC using "Provisioning API(https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/provisioning/v3/devguide)". I have done the first step: Authentication, Authorization and i got an access token, while doing the second step "Create an Account Ticket using the Provisioning API" getting an error "unauthorized access". Here is the code that i'm using for that:

```
    var requestBody = '{"kind":"analytics#accountTicket",' +
    '"account":{"name":"GATest"},"webproperty":{"name":"MyPortal","websiteUrl":"mywebappsurl"},' +
    '"Scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.provision",' +
    '"profile":{name:"PortalDev"},"redirectUri":"http://localhost:56599/Home/Tos/"}';
    alert(body);

    var response = $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/provisioning/createAccountTicket",
        method: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
        success: function (response) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

One thing that i know is i'm not mentioning the access token anywhere in this request, but i don't know where it need to be specify.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the top of the documentation for the [provisioning API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/provisioning/v3/) you will see.

> The Provisioning API is available by invitation only. We are not
>   currently accepting new projects.

You are not going to be able to use this API unless you have permission from Google to use it.  If I am not mistake you do not have access to use this api.  If I am mistake and you do have access then that access should come with some direct contact to Google I think you should contact them they may need to flag your project to enable it to use the API as this API is very restricted.